# How to split a string into multiple variables based on separator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string variable var1 which has value  `abc_123_xyz_321_123_123`  in python there are always 6 values separated by underscore  "_"
but the values are dynamic meaning there could be different values depending on different scenarios.

I am trying to store each value into a different variable like this :

```
a=abc
b=123
c=xyz
d=321
e=123
f=123
```

I tried this :

```
a,b,c,d,e,f=a,b = var1.split('_');

print(a,b,c,d,e,f)
```

But I don't think its correct way of doing it.

**Update :**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/r/Desktop/f1.py", line 30, in threaded
    a,b,c,d,e,f=a,b = var1.split('_');
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

**Update 2:**

this is the full segment of code:

```
    data = c.recv(1024)
    dataa1=data.decode("utf-8") 
    #print(dataa1)
    var1=dataa1[0]
    a,b,c,d,e,f = var1.split('_');
```

and this is the error :

```
a,b,c,d,e,f = var1.split('_');
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 6, got 1)
```

Comment: why do you think `a,b,c,d,e,f = var1.split('_')` is not correct? of course you can always work with the list returned by `split()` and access elements by index...

Comment: why do you have `=a, b` there, just do `a,b,c,d,e,f = var1.split('_');` or better store in a list `lst = var1.split('_');` and use indexing to access individual ones: `lst[0]`, `lst[1]` and so on.

Comment: Seems perfectly fine to me (other than the stray `a,b =` in the middle of the line that I assume is a typo). Why don't you think it's correct?

Comment: also note semi-colon at the end is redundant

Comment: it should be `a,b,c,d,e,f = var1.split('_')` - we thought it's a typo

Comment: ahhh sorry it was a typo but it was in the code

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your attempt to assign the result of `split` to the tuple `a, b`. Yo can, however, do something like this:

```
var1 = "abc_123_xyz_321_123_123"

a, b, c, d, e, f = head, *tail = var1.split("_")
print(a, b, c, d, e, f)
print(head, tail)
```

This splits the string both into 6 separate fields, and into the first and element and the rest of the elements, which, it seems, is what you attempted to do when assigning to `a, b`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of assigning value to `a,b,c,d,e,f` you can first assign to list and then list to a variable as split sometimes does not assign if the variable is more or if the split value is more. Try the below code.

```
var1 = "abc_123_xyz_321_123_123" # as split function works only on strings
list1 = var1.split("_");
a,b,c,d,e,f f = list1
```

Hope this solved your problem.

Comment: Using `list` as a variable name, while possible, is discouraged, as it will hide the built in type.